# CSS button link overlapping

Tags: html, css

**This is my HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Corruption in India</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="wrapper">
            <div id="header">
                <h1 id="heading">Corruption in India</h1>
            </div>
            <div id="menu">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="http://www.google.com">GOOGLE</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**And my CSS is**

```
#header {
    height:%;
    width:100%;
}

#heading {
    margin-top:20px;
    margin-left:5%;
    margin-right:25%;
}

#menu {

}

#wrapper {
    height:33%;
    background:-moz-linear-gradient(bottom,#A6BDF1,#122C67);
}

li {
    list-style-type:none; 
}

a {
    text-decoration:none;padding:4px 4px 4px 4px;
    background-color:#112759;
}
```

But the button link overlaps out. Please give me a way out.
I've given it a linear gradient and the syntax is mostly correct, looks like a design problem.

Comment: pot it in a fiddle please..

Comment: I've just put this code into my own fiddle and the link seems fine. Can you make your own fiddle with all your code so we can see the exact problem?

Comment: No Adam Botley ,Did you see how the link background comes just below the wrapper size

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this

**[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/dJHPV/4/)**

**css**

```
#heading {
 margin-top:20px;
 margin-left:5%;
 margin-right:25%;
}

#wrapper {
    height: 33%;
    background: #a6bdf1; /* Old browsers */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #a6bdf1 0%, #122c67 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#a6bdf1), color-stop(100%,#122c67)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #a6bdf1 0%,#122c67 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #a6bdf1 0%,#122c67 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #a6bdf1 0%,#122c67 100%); /* IE10+ */
background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #a6bdf1 0%,#122c67 100%); /* W3C */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#a6bdf1', endColorstr='#122c67',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */

    float:left;
    overflow:hidden;
    width:100%;

}
#menu {
}
#menu > ul{  
}
#menu > ul > li {
    list-style-type: none;
}
#menu > ul > li > a {
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 4px 4px 4px 4px;
    background-color: #112759;
    color:#ffffff;
}
```

Comment: Whoa! Thats too much help